# Slow data loading from firebase causing "RangeError (index)"

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Here i am trying to load image link from firebase into flutter app then passing it into image.network(). the data loading is taking time to load data so it is giving me following error: **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1** but after 5 second the data is loaded successfully and printed in console but not displayed on screen.  here is code to print data

```
class _DataFetching extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<eyes> allCriminals=eyes.allcriminals();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("fetch"),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            new Image.network(allCriminals[1].link
            ),

           ]// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    )));

  }
}
```

and function to load data from firebase is

```
 static  List<eyes> allcriminals() {
    var allEyes = new List<eyes>();
    Future<Query>  queryUsers() async{
      return await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child('Facial Parts/Eyes');
    }
    queryUsers().then((query) {
      query.once().then((snapshot) {
        var result =  snapshot.value.values as Iterable;
        for (var item in result) {
          print(result);
           allEyes.add(new eyes(criminal_id: item["criminal_id"],
              eye_size: item["eyesize"],
              link: item["link"]));

        print(item['link']);
        }

      });
    });
    return allEyes;
  }
```

is there any method that can help me to load all data and after  that it should go to Widget build()?

Comment: it looks like that you are not correctly awaiting for the result.
Since queryUsers is a future and you are not awaiting for it, it will return you the allEyes array that is empty.
Did you try use await before queryUsers() and see if it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `return allEyes` runs, the `.then()` from the database hasn't run yet. And you can't return something **now** that hasn't been loaded yet.

That's why you'll have to return a `Future<List<eyes>>`, which is a promise to have a list of eyes at some point in the future.

```
static Future<List<eyes>> allcriminals() {
  var query = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Facial Parts/Eyes');

  return query.once().then((snapshot) {
    var allEyes = new List<eyes>();
    var result = snapshot.value.values as Iterable;
    for (var item in result) {
       allEyes.add(new eyes(criminal_id: item["criminal_id"],
          eye_size: item["eyesize"],
          link: item["link"]));
    }
    return allEyes;
  });
}
```

Then you can use that in your render method by either using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) or by directly calling `setState()`.