# Flutter Function returns empty list using Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

I'm using Flutter web and firebase realtime database. In my databse I have some questions, structured as maps, and I'm trying to display them in my app.

For each question, I create a widget, I add it inside a list and then I append the list to a `Column()` widget.

The `Column()` widget is the following (`view_question.dart` file):

```
Column(
  children: Question().view(),
),
```

As you can see, I use the method `view()` from a class I created named `Question()`.

The `view()` method returns a list of widgets.

Before I show you the `.view()` method, I need to mention that outside of the `Question` class I have initialized the following:

```
List<Widget> widgets = List();
```

Below you can see the `.view()` method from the `Question` class (`Question.dart` file):

```
List<Widget> view() {
    
    Database db = database();
    DatabaseReference ref = db.ref('questions/');

    ref.orderByKey().once("value").then((e) {
      DataSnapshot datasnapshot = e.snapshot;
      datasnapshot.val().forEach((key, values) {
        
        widgets.add(QuestionWidget(values));
        print(widgets);
        
      });
    });
    print(widgets);
    return widgets;
```

I'm getting my questions' data from my database, then for each question I'm creating a `QuestionWidget()` widget, where I pass inside it the respective data and I add it to the `widgets` list. Afterwards, I `print()` the `widgets` list, so I can monitor the whole process.

As you also can see, I've added a `print(widgets)` just before the `return` statement.

This is the prints' output in my console

[image]

From that, what I understand is that the function returns an empty list and then I retrieve my data from the database and add them to the list.

So I'm asking, how can I add my data to the list, and when this process has finished, return the list and append it to the `Column()` widget? Should I add a delay to the return statement? What am I missing?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `return widgets` runs, the `widgets.add(QuestionWidget(values))` hasn't been called yet. If you check the debug output of your app, the `print` statements you have should show that.

For this reason you should set the `widgets` in the state once they're loaded. That will then trigger a repaint of the UI, which can pick them up from the state. Alternatively you can use a `FutureBuilder` to handle this process.

See:

- [How can I put retrieved data from firebase to a widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448903/how-can-i-put-retrieved-data-from-firebase-to-a-widget-in-flutter/63449008#63449008)
- [Slow data loading from firebase causing "RangeError (index)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320383/slow-data-loading-from-firebase-causing-rangeerror-index/62326064#62326064)

Comment: Thank you! Your first link in your comment and Rajitha's answer (the second answer here) led me to return the list correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // return type is like this
    Future<List<Widget>> view() {
    
    Database db = database();
    DatabaseReference ref = db.ref('questions/');

    // return this
    return ref.orderByKey().once("value").then((e) {
      DataSnapshot datasnapshot = e.snapshot;

      datasnapshot.val().forEach((key, values) {
        widgets.add(QuestionWidget(values));
      });
      
      // return widgets after added all values
      return widgets;
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be an async function? By the way, I used your answer and helped me setting up the .view() method correctly. I replaced your `Future<List<Widget>> view() ` with `Future<List> view() async`. Thank you!